# Does a Do-While loop break a For Each-Next Loop?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, nested

I'm trying to make sure that a range has visible rows before I act on those visible rows (delete them) because if I try to act on a filtered range when there aren't any visible rows there, I'll get an error.

```
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim ws as Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate

        ws.Range("$A$8").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        lastrow = ActiveCell.Row

        'DELETE PART CLASSES ROWS
        ActiveSheet.Range("$O$7:$O$" & lastrow & "").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        Array("CONS", "MISC", "PFG", "PRT", "TOTE", "="), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues

        Range("$A$8").Select
        Do
            If ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("$O$8:$O$" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.DELETE
                Exit Do
            End If
        While ActiveCell.Row < lastrow

        Range("$O$8").AutoFilter Field:=1

Next
```

The code block was working fine until I added the Do-If-While nested loops.  I now get the Compile error: Next without For

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't your `Do While` need a `Loop`? `Do .. IF .. End if .. Loop While...`

Comment: ^this. `Do <statements> Loop While <condition>`

Comment: Simple typographical / syntax error.  VTC

Comment: Also you should really avoid using `.Select` and `.ActiveCell` as it can cause tons of reference problems... [See this post for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [appears](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html) your `do`/`while` loop should be written like this:

```
Do
    If ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("$O$8:$O$" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.DELETE
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop While ActiveCell.Row < lastrow
```

If you wish to have a plain `while` loop that always evaluates the condition, rather than not evaluating it the first time, you need to write it like this:

```
Do While ActiveCell.Row < lastrow
    If ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("$O$8:$O$" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.DELETE
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting row by row, delete them all.  You're going about it in a really complicated way.  All you have to do is search for the first unfiltered row.  I do this by searching for the first empty cell below the header in the very last column (which works unless you use every single column available, which is really, really unlikely.)

```
Sub deleteUnfiltered()
'
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    headerRow = 1

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        ws.Activate
        lastCol = Columns.Count
        firstRow = Columns(lastCol).Find(What:="", After:=Cells(headerRow, lastCol), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row

        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, headerRow).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow <= headerRow Then lastRow = firstRow

        Rows(firstRow & ":" & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Next

End Sub
```

I'd think that looping row by row would be much slower than doing them all in one shot.